# Can you change the type of cons (:) in haskell

Tags: haskell

Cons has the input as a -> [a] -> [a]

Can you change cons to be

a -> a -> a

without a list type?

Comment: Why would you want to?  What's your actual goal?

Comment: Like if you had to do a recursive function with String -> String or Int -> Int.  Cons changes them to a list so I wanted to know if it was possible to change cons

Comment: `(:)` doesn't *change* anything; it's a data constructor that creates a new list given an existing list and another item of the appropriate type. What would you expect something like `3 : 4` to create, anyway?

Comment: You can't change cons, but you can use a different function.

Comment: If we had `(:) :: a -> a -> a` then `1 : [2,3,4]` would not type check - why would one like that? Also, by parametricity, a function of type `a -> a -> a` can only be one of the two projections `\x y -> x` and `\x y -> y`. We don't want cons to behave like any of those (not to break parametricity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot change the type of `(:)`. It is defined in Prelude. If you want a function with a different type, you just need to write that function yourself and give it an appropriate name.